# C#: How can I combine a switch with an if-statement?

Tags: c#, .net, switch-statement, if-statement

I need to combine a switch with an if-statement.

How can I do that? I want to do something like this:

```
switch (periodtype)
{
    if(starttime>endtime)
    {
        ;
    }
    else
    {
        case 0: nextRunTime = nextRunTime.AddHours(period); break;
        case 1: nextRunTime = nextRunTime.AddMinutes(period); break;
        case 2: nextRunTime = nextRunTime.AddSeconds(period); break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What is it that you are attempting to achieve?

Comment: he/she wants an if statement in a switch but with case functionalities :P

Comment: Too many clone answers, it'll be great if people can look into existing answers before posting new

Comment: switch wihout a default? that caused me a lot of heartburn recently.

Answer (score 15):

What's wrong with:

```
if(starttime<=endtime)
{
    switch (periodtype)
    {
        case 0: nextRunTime = nextRunTime.AddHours(period); break;
        case 1: nextRunTime = nextRunTime.AddMinutes(period); break;
        case 2: nextRunTime = nextRunTime.AddSeconds(period); break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(starttime>endtime)
{
    // Stuff
}
else
{
    switch (periodtype)
    {
        case 0: nextRunTime = nextRunTime.AddHours(period); break;
        case 1: nextRunTime = nextRunTime.AddMinutes(period); break
        case 2: nextRunTime = nextRunTime.AddSeconds(period); break;
    }
}
```

Like that?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(starttime>endtime)
{
    ;
}
else
{
   switch (periodtype)
   {
      case 0: nextRunTime = nextRunTime.AddHours(period); break;
      case 1: nextRunTime = nextRunTime.AddMinutes(period); break;
      case 2: nextRunTime = nextRunTime.AddSeconds(period); break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(starttime <= endtime)
{
      switch (periodtype)
      {     
             case 0: nextRunTime = nextRunTime.AddHours(period); break;
             case 1: nextRunTime = nextRunTime.AddMinutes(period); break;
             case 2: nextRunTime = nextRunTime.AddSeconds(period); break;

       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm way too late with answer

isnt this easier:

```
if (starttime <= endtime)
{
    switch (periodtype)
    {   
        case 0: nextRunTime = nextRunTime.AddHours(period); break;
        case 1: nextRunTime = nextRunTime.AddMinutes(period); break;
        case 2: nextRunTime = nextRunTime.AddSeconds(period); break;
    }
}
```